# Administrator not an Administrator?

Tags: windows-7, windows-xp, security, permissions, acl

I have copied some files from an XP computer to a PC running Windows 7. I am logged on as a user who is marked as an Administrator.

When I try to access the directory, I am told I don't have permission. Understandable, but what is odd is that I as an administrator don't have access to take ownership of the files. I don't have permission to add users in the ACL or to take ownership, indeed such options are greyed out.

Why as an administrator user can I not take ownership of files?

Comment: You don't even have the option to take ownership and then change permissions??

Comment: This happened to me once on XP, but was easily fixed by a reboot. I don't know why, it doesn't make any sense, but maybe this could work for you, too?

Comment: No, it's greyed out where I would select/search for users...

Comment: it *is* possible to (un)intentionally mark yourself as having no access to a file or folder. in this case you might try having another administrator try taking ownership and then see if they can grant you access to it

Answer (score 4):

Try opening an elevated CMD window (right click> Run as Administrator) and type:

```
Net user administrator /active:yes
```

Confirm the command ran successfully then log off and log back in as the administrator account. After logging in as the built-in administrator account you should be able to take ownership.

Do not use this account for anything other than troubleshooting, never for everyday use.

If you wish To disable the account:

Net user administrator /active:no

Comment: Ah, this didn't work. I still don't have permission and the options are still greyed out as per my normal user account (which is also an Administrator).

Comment: @sonny you are still unable to take ownership?

Comment: Yes, I just get that I don't have permission to do this. Oddly enough even on the XP computer I get the same error with the XP administrator account.

Comment: That's very odd @sonny, I had the same problem when I first migrating to windows 7 and it worked for me. I can't think of what else could be causing it unless you used, deny permissions but even then you should be able to take ownership.

Comment: Oh yeah thanks @moab for the edit extremely valid point... in terms of UAC that would be like running as root.

Comment: Yes, running in the hidden admin account disables UAC and protected mode in Internet Explorer.

Comment: Well, even on the XP computer, the administrator account doesn't have access to the quetzal folder. I have never seen this and am having trouble remedying it.

Comment: I have never seen this either @sonny. Do you see any random SID's that do have permissions or are they entirely blank?

Comment: on XP the owner SID is recognized and has permission...the SID isn't recognized on windows 7 so appears as random...

Comment: Wow so it recognizes the SID and has permissions but you still can't do anything with the files? if you have permissions on XP can you try adding the "everyone" group?

Comment: I did that, but it doesn't let me replace permissions on child objects at all.

Comment: there is a box you have to tick to replace it on child objects make sure these permissions aren't being inherited from a parent directory. Both these options are under advanced in the security tab.

Comment: Yep, ticket that, but just get permission denied when trying to make any change.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with my Windows 7 64-bit.  I was finally able to do it as mentioned above by running `Command Prompt` as Administrator and then executing the following Batch File from the Dos Shell.

```
SET DIRECTORY_NAME="C:\Windows.old.000"
TAKEOWN /f %DIRECTORY_NAME% /r /d y
ICACLS %DIRECTORY_NAME% /grant administrators:F /t
PAUSE
```

Replace `DIRECTORY_NAME` with your directory you want to delete.  This way you don't have to logout and come back in as a real Administrator instead of your normal login with Administrator "rights".

I do agree as mentioned above that one should not do everyday work as an Administrator.